# Report with a Date Range?

Tags: reporting, opportunity, custom-field, date, custom-report-type

Is it possible to create an opportunity report that reviews opportunities by a date range field (like January-February) instead of a singular date field (like "Created Date")?

Answer (score 2):

You can use two filters, such as "Created Date greater or equal Jan 1, 2022 AND Created Date less or equal Feb 28, 2022", or you can use a [relative date filter](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.filter_dates_relative.htm&type=5), such as "Created Date equals NEXT 2 MONTHS" or "Created Date equals THIS MONTH, NEXT MONTH".